# ROW_NUM() OR DNSE_RANK() Which one should be used and how should I use it?

Tags: sql, db2, row-number, db2-luw

I have below table and would like to get the result in ROW_NUM Column.

I tried this but don't get what I need.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DATE, SURG?, CODE  ORDER BY ID)
```

[image]

Comment: Please, don't post pictures. It would be good, if you explained the enumeration algorithm desired by words, and not just "I want this number for that row without any explanation"...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein for your help!! I am personally visual, so I thought would be great to show the picture.

Comment: Please, mark the answer as accepted, if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  T.*
, DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DATE ORDER BY "SURG?", CODE) AS ROW_NUM
FROM
(
VALUES
  (10198, 'SURG',  '06/14/2021', 58571)
, (10198, 'OTHER', '06/17/2021', 88307)  
, (10198, 'SURG',  '06/17/2021', 57425)
, (10198, 'SURG',  '06/17/2021', 57425)
, (10198, 'SURG',  '06/17/2021', 58571)
, (10198, 'SURG',  '06/17/2021', 58571)
) T (ID, "SURG?", DATE, CODE)
```

| ID | SURG? | DATE | CODE | ROW_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10,198 | SURG | 06/14/2021 | 58,571 | 1 |
| 10,198 | OTHER | 06/17/2021 | 88,307 | 1 |
| 10,198 | SURG | 06/17/2021 | 57,425 | 2 |
| 10,198 | SURG | 06/17/2021 | 57,425 | 2 |
| 10,198 | SURG | 06/17/2021 | 58,571 | 3 |
| 10,198 | SURG | 06/17/2021 | 58,571 | 3 |